# jqGrid editing ONLY through form mode

Tags: jquery, forms, jqgrid, inline

In my grids on the page, all of them need to not only have inline edit disabled, but ALSO should be editable via the modal form ONLY.

However, turning editable : false, while preventing in-line edits, also prevents editing via the form (no columns can be seen on the form, just the Submit and Cancel buttons)

How can I effect this behavior? Or is it not possible with the current version (3.5.2)

I also tried to enable editable (:true) (after having turned it off in the colModel declaration) within the beforeFormShow and onInitializeForm event handlers, but there are no columns displayed in either the edit or add forms.

Thanks very much for any insight you provide...

Here's what I'm doing -

```
           var addprm = { 
                     width: 450, 
                     height: 200,
                     top: 125, 
                     left: 50, 
                     beforeShowForm: function(formId) {
                         id= jQuery('#list10').getGridParam('selrow');
                         alert('From AddPrm: formId=' + formId + " id=" + id);
                         var ret = jQuery('#table').getRowData(id);
                         jQuery('#list10').setColProp('tr_a_name',{editable:true});
                         jQuery('#list10').setColProp('tr_a_desc',{editable:true});
                         jQuery('#list10').setColProp('tr_a_comments',{editable:true});
                     },  
                     reloadAfterSubmit:true, 
                     closeAfterAdd:true
             };
```

And like wise for the editprm object, with the tr_ prefix and without (as in colModel)

Comment: You make the task unnecessarily complex. Please try to follow Ed. Answer. Also try to accept the correct answer if you find it correct to continue to ask questions in this great community.

Answer (score 1):

I belive you can override the onSelectRow method so that it does not trigger a row_edit response and forces a model response. like so:

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid({
  ....init stuff.....
  onSelectRow: function(id){
     jQuery("#grid_id").editGridRow( id, properties );
  }
  .....other stuff......
 })
```